# One word for someone "excessively sentimental" in everything

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

Someone who makes you sick with his sentimental blabber.

I have a colleague who cribs and complains at almost everything. He would always get sentimental while describing his misadventures or failures.

Comment: [affected, affectionate, bathetic, corny, demonstrative, dewy-eyed,
dreamy, effusive, gushing, idealistic, impressionable, jejunes, anguishing, lovey-dovey,
lovings, maudlin, mawkish, moonstruck, mushy, nostalgic, overacted, overemotional...](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gushy)

Comment: One more to add to the above list is sappy. Maudlin, mawkish and corny are good choices from that above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Mawkish, adj.:](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mawkish)** **1660s, "sickly, nauseated," from Middle English mawke "maggot". [Sense of "sickly sentimental" is first
>   recorded 1702](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mawkish&allowed_in_frame=0).**
>
> **[Soppy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/soppy)**:  showing or feeling too much of emotions such as love or sympathy, rather than being reasonable or practical.

(cambridge.org/etymonline.com)

Answer (score 1):

"**slushy"** comes to mind.

> - slushy - (adj)   "affectedly or extravagantly emotional" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slushy)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for one of (definitions from dictionary.com):

- [mushy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mushy?s=t)

  > Informal. overly emotional or sentimental:
  >   mushy love letters.
- [soppy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soppy?s=t)

  > British Slang. excessively sentimental; mawkish.
- [saccharine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/saccharine)

  > 4. cloyingly agreeable or ingratiating: a saccharine personality.
  > 5. exaggeratedly sweet or sentimental: a saccharine smile; a saccharine song of undying love.